# Flask WTForms FieldList with BooleanField

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I'd like to generate list of files with checkboxes. I've tried to use FieldList but it doesn't work as I expected. Instead of checkbox with assigned filename I'm getting checkbox with label named after the variable containing FieldList object. Is there any way to fix it?

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField, FieldList, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'development'
Bootstrap(app)

filenames = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg']


class FileListForm(FlaskForm):
    filename = FieldList(BooleanField(), 'Files')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/')
def listfiles():
    form = FileListForm()
    for filename in filenames:
        form.filename.append_entry(filename)
    return render_template('index.html',
                           form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

templates/index.html

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```

packages:

```
click==6.7
dominate==2.3.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, WTForms' [`FieldList`](http://pythonhosted.org/WTForms/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) shouldn't be used with [`BooleanField`](http://pythonhosted.org/WTForms/fields.html#wtforms.fields.BooleanField):

> Note: Due to a limitation in how HTML sends values, `FieldList` cannot enclose `BooleanField` or `SubmitField` instances.

(Even though the HTML output appears valid.) That said, you're not seeing what you're expecting to see because `append_entry`'s first parameter accepts the form input's value, not its label.

Instead, I'd recommend creating the form class dynamically:

```py
filenames = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg']

class FileListFormBase(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

def file_list_form_builder(filenames):
    class FileListForm(FileListFormBase):
        pass

    for (i, filename) in enumerate(filenames):
        setattr(FileListForm, 'filename_%d' % i, BooleanField(label=filename))

    return FileListForm()

@app.route('/')
def listfiles():
    form = file_list_form_builder(filenames)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Note: The default HTML representation will have the "Submit" button at the top, since the library renders fields in the order they're defined. WTForms doesn't natively support ordering, so this may be a better solution for you even though it's less elegant:

```py
filenames = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg']

def file_list_form_builder(filenames):
    class FileListForm(FlaskForm):
        pass

    for (i, filename) in enumerate(filenames):
        setattr(FileListForm, 'filename_%d' % i, BooleanField(label=filename))

    setattr(FileListForm, 'submit', SubmitField('Submit'))
    return FileListForm()

@app.route('/')
def listfiles():
    form = file_list_form_builder(filenames)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Can somebody please amend the jinja code for displaying the checkbox with name `filename_i` in the html template??

Comment: @RainerGlüge hey did you ever figure out the jinja code for this?

Comment: This solution is great. I just can't figure out how to render the fields individually in Jinja. 
Rendering the entire form at once doesn't really work for my situation. Has anyone figured out how to do this? Even if I were to send list of all my fieldnames to the template, I'm still not sure how to use them correctly. {% for var_name in var_list %}
{{ form.{{var_name}} }} {% endfor %} I'm don't think you can nest the double bracket tag inside of one, but I guess I'll try and report back.

Comment: I passed in extra info to precheck checkboxes:

Comment: I passed in extra info as `feld` to precheck checkboxes: 
`{% for entry in feld[cuindex] %}
{% if entry=='checked CB'%}
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" id="col_{{ loop.index-1 }}" mame="col_{{loop.index-1}}" type="checkbox" value="y" checked>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if entry=='empty CB'%}
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" id="col_{{ loop.index-1 }}" name="col_{{loop.index-1}}" type="checkbox" value="y">
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone in the future. This is how I implemented the jinja part of this solution.

I created a list of variable names to send to the template.
In my case I needed to dynamically create several fields based on a count.
These names need to match the names you created while building the form, such as in the selected solution for this given problem above.

```
variable_names_list = []
for i in range(1, count+1):
    variable_names_list.append([f'var1_name_{i}',f'var2_name_{i}',f'var3_name_{i}',f'var4_name_{i}'])
```

Send this to template in your render template statement
And then use the following jinja to in order to show your form items

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                                {% for variable_names in variable_names_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    {% for variable in variable_names %} 
                                        <td>
                                            {{ form[variable] }}
                                        </td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>

                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>
```

The key part of this solution is this line:

```
{{ form[variable] }}
```

It took me a while to figure out this is how one can access the form items individually.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Cheers