# unboundfield object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

An error occurs. I tried to alternate booleanfield and integerfield, but this error occurs.

```
{% block content %}
  File "C:\Users\Killu\Desktop\EGE pass\templates\add_result.html", line 19, in block 'content'
    {{ form.checkboxes_fields[i + 1]() }}
TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable
```

```
        <div>
            <form method="POST">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>{{subject.capitalize()}}</legend>
                    <div class="grid">
                        {% for i, task in enumerate(tasks)%}
                        {% if task == 1 %}
                        <div>
                            <label for="checkbox{{i + 1}}">№{{i + 1}}</label>
                            {{ form.checkboxes_fields[i + 1]() }}
                        </div>
                        {% else %}
                        <div>
                            <label for="number{{i + 1}}">№{{i + 1}}</label>
                            {{ for number in form.checkboxes_fields }}
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

```
class AdditionResultsForm(FlaskForm):
    checkboxes_fields = [BooleanField(f"{i}") for i in range(40)]
    numb_fields = [IntegerField(f"{i}", default=0) for i in range(50)]
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить результат')
```

I really dont know why it happened, i try to do this on test project and on test project its work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The issue in that simple lists don't support fields of Flask-WTF, therefore you should use **FieldList** with parameter `min_entries`:

```
class AdditionResultsForm(FlaskForm):
    # checkboxes_fields = BooleanField(f"{i}") for i in range(40)]
    numb_fields = FieldList(IntegerField(f"{i}", default=0), min_entries=50)
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить результат')
```

But, according to [Flask-WTF Documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#field-enclosures), you can't use it for BooleanField:

> Note: Due to a limitation in how HTML sends values, FieldList cannot enclose BooleanField or SubmitField instances.

You can try to do it creating the form class [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653424/flask-wtforms-fieldlist-with-booleanfield), but don't sure that it'll be work:

```
class AdditionResultsFormBase(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить результат')

def checkboxes_fields(filenames):
    class AdditionResultsForm(AdditionResultsFormBase):
        pass

    for i in range(40):
        setattr(AdditionResultsForm, BooleanField(f"{i}"))

    return AdditionResultsForm()
```